# How to convert a string to "04x" hex in little endian format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, endianness

When I convert the a string in 04x hex it will be like this,

```
"".join("{:04x}".format(ord(c)) for c in "USERDOMAIN")
==> 00550053004500520044004f004d00410049004e
```

However I need it in little endian format? In this example

```
==> 550053004500520044004f004d00410049004e00
```

How should I calculate this value (I mean little endian format of USERDOMAIN 04x hex) in python?

Comment: Are you trying to produce *UTF-16* bytes perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to encode to UTF16 bytes, just do so:

```
u'USERDOMAIN'.encode('utf-16-le')
```

which encodes to UTF-16, little endian, without a Byte Order Mark:

```
>>> u'USERDOMAIN'.encode('utf-16-le')
'U\x00S\x00E\x00R\x00D\x00O\x00M\x00A\x00I\x00N\x00'
>>> u'USERDOMAIN'.encode('utf-16-le').encode('hex')
'550053004500520044004f004d00410049004e00'
```

Note that I created a *Unicode literal* by prefixing the string definition with `u`. If you have a bytestring from another source, you'll have to decode to Unicode first unless that data is ASCII only.